# Why is $2\sin{(akx)}\sin{(bkx)}=\cos{((a-b)kx)}-\cos{((a+b)kx)}$?

Tags: trigonometry, quantum-mechanics

I am learning introductory quantum mechanics from the Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths.

I stumbled upon this proof for orthogonality of two different solutions regarding the infinite well problem on the page 33:
[image: Proof]

I have some problems understanding the passage from the first line to the second line. Why is
$$\frac{2}{a}\sin{\left(\frac{m\pi}{a}x\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)}=\frac 1 a \cos{\left(\frac{m-n}{a}\pi x\right)}-\cos{\left(\frac{m+n}{a}\pi x\right)}$$
true? I haven't yet found any way to solve it using trigonometric identities.

There are lots of physics variables here, but this is Mathematics Stack Exchange. That's why I can ask it in the generalised way:

---

In general, why is
$$2\sin{(akx)}\sin{(bkx)}=\cos{((a-b)kx)}-\cos{((a+b)kx)}$$
true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [product to sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

> $$2\sin \theta \sin \varphi = {{\cos(\theta - \varphi) - \cos(\theta + \varphi)} }$$

which can be proved by angle sum and difference identities.

Refer to the related

- [Proving the Sum to Product Identities (without using the product to sum identities)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3436028/505767)

Comment: Oh, there's a theorem about it. (BTW, I just wanted to ask how it is proved, and you had already added the insight of the proof : )

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities especially the figures next to that paragraph

Comment: Thank you for the theorem. I think there just can't be a better answer and this answers it perfectly. That's why I am going to accept it as soon as I can do it.

Comment: @User123 I've added a reference with the proof.